# Must all field theories depend on the spatial derivate of the fields?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, locality

For instance, if I have encountered

\begin{equation}
\label{eqq2}
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_i \phi)} = 0
\end{equation}

This tells us that $\mathcal{L}$ cannot depend on $\partial_i \phi$, only on the field $\phi$ and it's time-derivative $\dot{\phi}$.

Does this go against some rule for field theories? If so, I can say ok, the Lagrangian must not only depend on the things I guessed it did in my ansatz.

Answer (score 4):

If a field theory does not depend on the spatial derivatives of any of the fields involved, then the equations of motion will only depend on temporal derivatives;  its form will be something like
$$
\mathcal{D}_t \phi(t, \vec{r}) = f(\phi(t,\vec{r}))
$$
where $\mathcal{D}_t$ is an differential operator in $t$ only.

This is not in and of itself a bad thing, but it does preclude a lot of interesting behavior that you would want field theories to have.  In particular, this evolution equation is really just an infinite number of uncoupled ODEs, with the position $\vec{r}$ effectively only acting as an index over the quantities we're interested in.  This means that the field evolution at a given point $\vec{r}$ will be completely determined by the field's initial values at the point $\vec{r}$;  it will not depend on the field's initial values at any other point in space.  This precludes solutions involving things like diffusion or wave propagation.

Comment: That is what I thought! So essentially, let's say for a scalar field, the only behavior we could see is something like ... 
@ t=0, 00300
 and then 
@ t= delta t, 00700? Or is it more like 

@ t=0, 00300
 and then 
@ t= delta t, 00300

Comment: @LopeyTall:  The field can certainly evolve in time in this circumstance.  How (or whether) it evolves is determined by the equations of motion.   It can also vary from point to point in space.  The only real restriction is that the field evolution at point $A$ cannot influence the evolution at point $B$, or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Spatial derivatives allow us to encode *local* interactions between the value of the field at different points. Ultimately, wavelike solutions to the equations of motion which propagate information from one point to another, arise because of the local interactions encoded in the spatial derivative terms.

Therefore, without spatial derivatives, you have two options.

1. Do not include any coupling between spatial points. In this case, the field evolves at each point independently. (As Michael Seifert pointed out in his answer). Then, there is no way for information to propagate in space, and communication becomes impossible.
2. Include *non-local* couplings between spatial points. For example, you could have one scalar field and say that every point in spacetime has the same value of the scalar field. Or, you could multiply the value of the field at points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the Lagrangian. The lack of locality will lead to a violation of causality, if we assume special relativity is true.